# Div off page with a bg image, how to not scroll off the page

Tags: html, css

I have created a header image 2268px wide, with a normal header in the middle and then a background going off the page (support for larger monitors such as the mac).

I have set `overflow-x: hidden` on the parent element however I am still able to scroll across to it. So basically im trying to have a background image that doesnt send the page wonky.

HTML:

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
<div id="headerBg">
    </div><!-- End #headerBg -->
    <header id="branding" role="banner">
            <nav id="access" role="navigation">
                <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                <?php /* Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php /* Our navigation menu. If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assigned to the primary location is the one used. If one isn't assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- #access -->
    </header><!-- #branding -->
```

CSS

```
#headerBg{
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('img/headerBg.gif');
    margin-left: -633px;
    height: 362px;
    width: 2268px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry should have said, overflow-x is hidden on the parent, but you  can still mousewheel to the edge of the div

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Your `margin-left:-633px;` is causing the scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not setting the width and margin you don't get to the point where you need to set the parents overflow. Positioning the background centered, instead of the element itself *(with the negative margin)*, you can leave that out and the browser does it himself. Without scrollbars.

```
#headerBg {
    background-image: url('img/headerBg.gif');
    background-position: top center;
    height: 362px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is give it an automatic margin to center it on the page. That way you don't need the margin-left, which is causing it to scroll.

Comment: But it still has the width set which is allowing scroll?

Comment: That's why you need to disable overflow as you mentioned: http://jsfiddle.net/gfubW/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should simply add following to your CSS declaration:

```
#page {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

It disables the rendering of scrollbar caused by the oversized image. See http://jsfiddle.net/uXFT4/

Note that `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` might not be supported by all browsers you expect it to work. Use `overflow` if possible.